# How do I make my procedural Knapsack problem brute-forcer into an object-oriented one?

Tags: c++

This is my first shot at brute-forcing the NP-complete [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).  In this form you have a list of items which must be thrown off a plane each with a weight and cost.  The goal is to throw out some remain_weight while minimizing cost.

Each recursion level(y direction if graphed) is a new remain_weight after items have been selected.  A for loop searches through all the items(x direction if graphed)

```
Test Case 1 - Works
Item / Weight / Cost
0      100     101
1      300     297
```

What is the best way to put these two functions in a class.

```
enum item_type {weight, cost};
int algo(int &cost_low, int &cost_high, int throw_weight, int item_id, int item_matrix[][2])
{
    int quantity,remainder;
    quantity=throw_weight/item_matrix[item_id][weight];
    remainder=throw_weight%item_matrix[item_id][weight];
    if(remainder==0)
    {
        cost_low=(quantity-1)*item_matrix[item_id][cost];
        cost_high=quantity*item_matrix[item_id][cost];
        throw_weight-=(quantity-1)*item_matrix[item_id][weight];
    }
    else
    {
        cost_low=(quantity)*item_matrix[item_id][cost];
        cost_high=(quantity+1)*item_matrix[item_id][cost];
        throw_weight-=(quantity)*item_matrix[item_id][weight];
    }
    return throw_weight;
}
int branch(int remain_weight)
{
    static int depth_level = 0;
    static int cost_present=32000;
    int remain_weight_next;
    int cost_low, cost_high, cost_branch;
    depth_level++;
    cout << "Entering at depth: " << depth_level << " :remain_weight: " << remain_weight << endl ;
    int item_id, item_count=2; 
    int item_matrix[][2] = 
    {
        {100, 101},
        {300, 297},
    //  {400, 401},
    //  {800, 800}, 
    //  {1200, 1200}, 
    //  {1999, 1800},
    //  {2000, 2000},
    };
    for(item_id=0; item_id<item_count; ++item_id)
    {
        cout << "--For loop id is: " << item_id << endl; 
        if(item_matrix[item_id][weight]<remain_weight)
        {
            cout << "----item_weight: " << item_matrix[item_id][weight] << " : is less than remain_weight : " << remain_weight << endl;
            remain_weight_next=algo(cost_low,cost_high,remain_weight,item_id,item_matrix); 
            cost_branch = branch(remain_weight_next);
            cost_present=cost_low + cost_branch;  
            if(cost_present>cost_high)
                cost_present=cost_high;
            cout << "--**remain_weight: " << remain_weight << endl;
            cout << "--**cost_low: " << cost_low << endl;
            cout << "--**cost_high: " << cost_high << endl;
            cout << "--**cost_branch: " << cost_branch << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "----item_weight: " << item_matrix[item_id][weight] << " : is greater than remain_weight : " << remain_weight << endl;
            if(cost_present>item_matrix[item_id][cost])
                cost_present=item_matrix[item_id][cost];
        }
        cout << "--**cost_present: " << cost_present << endl;
    }
    cout << "Leaving at Depth: " << depth_level << endl;
    depth_level--;
    return cost_present;
}
```

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please add the homework tag (which you can do by editing your post). Knowing this (or other background) would help people answer, I think.

Comment: Also, I'm going to edit your title—at least to me, "solution to NP complete…" sounds like you're claiming an *efficient* solution, i.e., one in class P. Of course, if you actually had such a thing, no one would care if it was written with classes or not.

Comment: inerview question for two software companies

Comment: @derobert I see you inserted a ZWSP into the title. Please help me eradicate the source of the problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112944/the-title-word-filter-is-the-worst-idea-ever-implemented-on-so

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ: I've already voted for all the related "please fix this" on meta, not sure what else I can do to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int &cost_low, int &cost_high` is a tip-off. If a function is called repeatedly, and on each iteration modifies the same objects, then that function and those objects should probably be members of the same class.

If you look further, you see that `algo` also works on `cost_matrix[]` and `weight_matrix[]` (No, it's not a 2D array). These could also become members.

`branch` is a bit complex because you 're mixing up things. It's recursive, but you also initialize `item_matrix` in each and every recursion. No problem once you've moved `item_matrix` into a class; the ctor will then initialize it. But do allocate that class outside `branch()` for the same recursive reasons.

Finally, be a bit more compact. Don't define objects early; define them when you have a value. Dare to write `cout << "Entering at depth: " << ++depth_level;`

Comment: excellent info..thanks...so as I understand...1.) break up my 2D array in to 2 1D arrays and make class members.  2.) The pass by reference values need to be class members in the new class.  3.) I like compact too...will do....and just to make sure.  I can recurse "inside a class"...meaning I can have a class function call itself?..Also the reason for breaking up my 2D matrix?...thanks again

Comment: @ChrisAaker: Yes on all. The reason to break up the 2D matrix is because it's semantically incorrect. As a quick rule of thumb, if it doesn't make sense to iterate over, it's not an array, and you don't iterate over the second dimension here. A second indication is `enum item_type`. C++ has a perfectly good method of making types, don't roll your own. 2 Arrays isn't the only solution, though. You could reasonably have a single 1D array of `struct item { int cost; int weight}`